# My implementation of Breadth First Search with forEach doesn't work

Tags: javascript, algorithm, breadth-first-search

Here is my code inside a BinarySearchTree class. I don't know if it is because of the behaviour of forEach, or because somewhere in my code is wrong.

```
class BinarySearchTree {
    constructor() {
        this.root = null;

    }
    insert(val) {
        let newNode = new Node(val)
        if (!this.root) {
            this.root = newNode;
            return this;
        } else {
            let level = this.root
            //             if (val < level.value && level.left){
            //                 level = level.left
            while (true) {
                if (val < level.value) {
                    if (level.left) {
                        level = level.left
                    } else if (!level.left) {
                        level.left = newNode;
                        return this
                    }
                }
                else if (val > level.value) {
                    if (level.right) {
                        level = level.right
                    } else if (!level.right) {
                        level.right = newNode;
                        return this
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    BFS() {
        let data = [];
        let queue = [];
        if (!this.root) {
            return false
        } else if (this.root) {
            queue.push(this.root)
            while (queue.length) {
                queue.forEach(function (element) {
                    if (element.left) {
                        queue.push(element.left)
                    }
                    if (element.right) {
                        queue.push(element.right)
                    }
                    queue.shift()
                    data.push(element)
                })
            }
            return data
        }
    }

}
```

```
class Node {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }
}
```

Here is the input

```
tree.insert(50)
tree.insert(70)
tree.insert(43)
tree.insert(45)
tree.insert(18)
tree.insert(52)
tree.insert(59)
console.log(tree.BFS())
```

Here is the output

```
[
  Node {
    value: 50,
    left: Node { value: 43, left: [Node], right: [Node] },
    right: Node { value: 70, left: [Node], right: null }
  },
  Node {
    value: 43,
    left: Node { value: 18, left: null, right: null },
    right: Node { value: 45, left: null, right: null }
  },
  Node { value: 18, left: null, right: null },
  Node { value: 18, left: null, right: null },
  Node { value: 45, left: null, right: null }
]
```

As you can see, there are duplications and also some nodes of the tree aren't showed at all. Thank everyone in advance!

Comment: thank you, @JohnKugelman. I have edited the post and included the input as well as the output.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `forEach`, [you should not modify the underlying array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#modifying_the_array_during_iteration). All kinds of hard-to-understand behavior will result.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @JDB, you should not modify the underlying array in `forEach`.

Although you don't need to use `forEach` for `BFS` in this case as you are only traversing the tree. You can process one element at a time from the front of the queue until the queue is empty.

```js
class Node {
  constructor(value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.left = null;
    this.right = null;
  }
}

class BinarySearchTree {
  constructor() {
    this.root = null;
  }

  insert(val) {
    let newNode = new Node(val)
    if (!this.root) {
      this.root = newNode;
      return this;
    } else {
      let level = this.root
      //             if (val < level.value && level.left){
      //                 level = level.left
      while (true) {
        if (val < level.value) {
          if (level.left) {
            level = level.left
          } else if (!level.left) {
            level.left = newNode;
            return this
          }
        } else if (val > level.value) {
          if (level.right) {
            level = level.right
          } else if (!level.right) {
            level.right = newNode;
            return this
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  BFS() {
    let data = [];
    let queue = [];
    if (!this.root) {
      return false
    } else if (this.root) {
      queue.push(this.root)
      while (queue.length) {
        const element = queue[0]
        data.push(element)
        if (element.left) {
          queue.push(element.left)
        }
        if (element.right) {
          queue.push(element.right)
        }
        queue.shift()
      }
      return data
    }
  }
}

const tree = new BinarySearchTree();
tree.insert(50)
tree.insert(70)
tree.insert(43)
tree.insert(45)
tree.insert(18)
tree.insert(52)
tree.insert(59)
const result = tree.BFS()
for (r of result) console.log(r)
```